# Reading status from your friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Can I read status from my friends wall , using graph API or do I need FQL?

If so, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the Graph API, use the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=XXX

Remember to replace USER_ID with the id of the user who's feed you want to read, and pass your access token. The docs are at this url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

**EDIT**
Getting an access token can be quite tricky process in my experience. Which language are you using? You might wanner look into libraries which ease this process

Comment: I am using JAVA , I think its not fully supported or its deprecated , I know PHP , but I will do a lot of processing in my friends statuses , so what you think ?

Answer (score 0):

If you download facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com, you can do this from the PowerShell commandline as simply "Get-FBFeed -Id ". Facebook PowerShell Module will help you get and manage your Access Token.